# Review of home-school tag

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I noticed the [home-school](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home-school) tag on a recent question.

Currently, there are [three questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home-schooling) with that tag.  The first is OT for P.SE (belongs on codereview.SE) and the other two are already tagged with [teaching](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching).

I suggest we get rid of the [home-school](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home-school) tag as it doesn't generate any meaningful distinction from the [teaching](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teaching) tag.

So my question is to generate a discussion about the future of that tag in line with [jmort253's recent answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3851/53019) about tag discussions.

Comment: All the question have been retagged now so the tag will disappear from the suggestion list within the next 24 hours.

Comment: @ChrisF  Thanks!

Comment: Don't thank me - others did the retagging. I was just reporting what I just found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To follow up on my comment. Now that the tag has been removed from all existing questions it will disappear from the suggestions after 24 hours and will require users with [more than 300 reputation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-tags) to suggestion it again.

If it reappears we can request that it be blacklisted, but that's a last resort.